# Ion Slides Throws "_activeSlide is undefined" Error After slider.startAutoplay() is called

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

This issue has only come up when I try to use the autoplay feature.

I have tried to include the option in the html:

```
<ion-slides #homeSlides 
*ngIf="slides" 
autoplay="5000"
autoplayDisableOnInteraction="false"
initialSlide=0 
pager="true"
loop="true"
effect="fade"
autoHeight="true" >
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides" >
    <ion-card (click) = "openPage(slide.component)">
      <img id= "slide-img" [src]= "slide.img">
      <div class="card-title" text-wrap> {{slide.title}} </div>
      <div class="card-subtitle" text-wrap> {{slide.subtitle}} </div>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Also have tried enabling it in my component:

```
@ViewChild('homeSlides') slider: Slides;

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.slider.update();
  this.slider.autoplay = 5000;
  this.slider.startAutoplay();
```

}

With the second method the stacktrace is:

```
ERROR TypeError: s._activeIndex is undefined
Stack trace:
autoplay@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:42425:26
startAutoplay@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:42469:5
Slides.prototype.startAutoplay@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:55099:9
HomePage.prototype.ionViewDidLoad@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45351:9
ViewController.prototype._lifecycle@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:17317:13
ViewController.prototype._didLoad@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:17190:9
NavControllerBase.prototype._didLoad@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44560:13
....
```

I have looked through the Slides and Swiper implementations on [GitHub](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/) but I cannot find where _activeIndex (or activeIndex) gets a value other than `null`.

I know this is occurring on the autoplay() function at line 204 in the  [swiper.ts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/slides/swiper/swiper.ts) file.

Hopefully the source will help someone spot my mistake.

Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but when I try to use the [options] property and load in properties from an array I always get the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-slides'.
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this this.slider.update(); etc... in the ionViewDidLoad()? I don't know if there is any relation, but they are not needed.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added this as I was wondering if it was just a problem with the original construction of the Slides object, in which case update() would refresh it. Didn't work

Comment: donot need `initialSlide=0 `. if you want to add then define index to  ion-slides `let i of index` and remove `*ngIf="slides` its not so necessary.